# PHP Timezone different then Centos date

Tags: php, nginx, centos

I'm having some issues with my *php script*. For some reason the date function gives a totally different time then my servers date function.

For instance php date gives me:

```
Saturday 28th of March 2015 01:05:12 AM
```

While centos date gives me:

```
Fri Mar 27 18:05:12 PDT 2015
```

I noticed the issue because my contab's which are scheduled to run at midnight are running at the wrong time despite the server date time being correct.

I don't understand whats going on because this was working fine up until a few days ago.

Comment: if it was working fine up until a few days ago what have you changed during this time?

Comment: I haven't made any changes to any of the scripts. Maybe it was rebooted by my datacenter and upon turning back on something changed? No clue.

Answer (score 1):

The "totally different time" is really the same time, expressed in a different timezone.

CentOS "PDT" is indicating Pacific Daylight Time.  PHP is showing the time 7 hours ahead, which is "UTC" or "GMT", basically the "no time zone" time zone.

Look in your `/etc/php.ini` file for a line like this:

```
date.timezone = UTC
```

More information and available timezones are shown here:
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone

If you want to change the timezone for CentOS itself, you can look up more info on the `/etc/sysconfig/clock` file.

I actually encourage you to keep everything in UTC, as it avoids all TZ issues altogether, at the slight cost of a little mental arithmetic when you edit your crontab files.

Comment: I've changed the time in php.ini. I don't seem to have the clock file in my sysconfig folder nor do i have anything with the word clock in it. Should I create this file if it doesn't exist? Thanks